# Agregar MVC a una aplicacion asp.net (webform)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy modificando una aplicación asp.net (webform), la cual se me hace un poco difícil de manejar, ya que por lo general trabajo con mvc.

estoy intentando agregar System.Web.Mvc a la aplicacion asp, a través de nuget.

en el controller funciona todo correctamente, ya que al agregar la referencia System.Web.Mvc mis controladores heredan correctamente de la clase controller.

el problema lo tengo en las vistas, ya que la directiva @model no me la reconoce el compilador. sin eso no puedo pasar datos a la vista  (la manipulo con razor que tb esta instalado).

alguien ha trabajado antes de esta manera? 
se que es algo inusual, pero realmente no tengo opción de pasar la app escrita originalmente en asp a Mvc, y el asp.net se me hace un problema manejarlo por mi poca experiencia.

gracias por leer.
Saludos

Comment: No es tan inusual :-) Seguro esto te sirve: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Comment: Si más no me equivoco en WebForm no hay controladores pero creo que existen los codebehind http://www.creatuwebnicaragua.com/que-es-el-code-behind/ que puedes usar como tal.

Comment: Estimados, gracias por sus comentarios. Finalmente opte por el camino largo, y le puse un poco de esfuerzo a asp.net. Igualmente encontre interesante el planteamiento en el blog de scott hanselman, aunque ya no me es necesario el procedimiento. Muchas gracias por el tiempo. Saludos